# List of brightcove BEML iconName

Tags: brightcove

Loking for list of defined iconName.

Any idea where i can find a the list of the predefined names for iconName, used in the Button tag in BEML.

thnx
Mark

Answer (score 0):

You might find what you are looking for [here](http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/components-player-templates)

or [here](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/beml/index.html)

Comment: looking for iconName= what are the names i can use
can't find it on brightcove site.

Answer (score 0):

> The possible values of iconName and toggledIconName are: **menu, play, pause, volume, maximize, minimize, share, link, code**.

Source: [Components in Player Templates](http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/components-player-templates)